# How to show the compiler version of Visual Studio using library functions?

Tags: c, visual-studio

In C program, I want to display the current version of compiler which was used in the program. Like,

```
char *version;
version = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
strcpy(version, ??? ); 
printf("Current compiler version is ...%s", version);
```

In this case, what should I put in "???" blank?

I guess there is MACRO somewhere showing what I want...

Comment: [Use _MSC_VER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: add the tag visual studio

Comment: Note that doing this makes your program completely unusable on other systems. Do you really want that? It's a newbie mistake to think that all the world's a Windows box with VS.

Comment: @Jens Hmm.. I just want to check how type size would be different such as int, short, double.. depending on compiler version. Plus, I want to show sizes and version on output in same time. ;P

Comment: OK, then the correct solution is to look at the values defined in `<limits.h>`, which is a Standard C header available everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print **_MSC_VER** to get just the MSC version.

Print **_MSC_FULL_VER** to get the full MSC version.

Try this!

```
printf("Current compiler version is ...%d\n", _MSC_VER);
printf("Current compiler full version is ...%d\n", _MSC_FULL_VER);
```

It is an integer MACRO. So, hold it in an int.

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx
 for macros _MSC_VER, _MSC_BUILD and _MSC_FULL_VER.